# Using socket.io with React and Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, socket.io

I've created a Node(express)/React app that uses socket.io and Redux's store as follows:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import * as types from "../actions/types";
import { cancelReview, startReview } from "./actions";

const socket = io("http://localhost:8080", {
  transports: ["websocket"]
});

export const init = store => {
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("websocket connection successful...");
    socket.on("cancelReview", (id, name) => {
      cancelReview(store, id, name);
    });
    socket.on("startReview", (id, name) => {
      startReview(store, id, name);
    });
  });
};
```

This function is then called from store.js as follows:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { init } from "./socket/socket";

// Initial state
const initialState = {};

// Middleware
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

init(store);

export default store;
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, but I'm now realizing after doing some research that this will not work on Google's app engine because instead of `http://localhost:8080` I need to get the actual IP address from Google's metadata server and pass in `EXTERNAL_IP + ":65080"`. So I'm able to get the external IP in my express app as follows:

```
const METADATA_NETWORK_INTERFACE_URL =
  "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip";

function getExternalIp(cb) {
  const request = axios.create({
    baseURL: METADATA_NETWORK_INTERFACE_URL,
    headers: { "Metadata-Flavor": "Google" }
  });
  request
    .get("/", (req, res) => {
      return cb(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error while talking to metadata server, assuming localhost");
      return cb("localhost");
    });
}
```

However, if I pass this value into my render function as seen below, React creates a prop to pass into components (as far as I understand from the info I could find):

```
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    getExternalIp(extIp => {
      res.render(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"), {
        externalIp: extIp
      });
    });
```

I am not able to access this value via the window global. So my question is, how do I access this external IP from my store initialization, since it is not an actual React component?

Thanks in advance.